# Draw a ruler with a fixed value in Altair?

Tags: python, altair

I would like to mark up a line in my chart, but when specifying the value of that number using `alt.XValue()` the number is not aligned with the graphs using this axis.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()
base = alt.Chart(source)

error_bars = base.mark_errorbar(extent='stdev').encode(
  x=alt.X('yield:Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
  y=alt.Y('variety:N')
)

points = base.mark_point(filled=True, color='black').encode(
  x=alt.X('yield:Q', aggregate='mean'),
  y=alt.Y('variety:N'),
)

base = base.mark_rule(color='red', strokeDash=[4, 2]).encode(
    x=alt.XValue(41)
)
error_bars + points + base
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure *why* that doesn't work, but if you use a dataframe with one value instead it works fine (`alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'x':[41]}))`).

Comment: Indeed, I did that before, but it felt hacky to me and I thought to ask. The other option may be to use a transform, but with the same downside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time you specify a value to an encoding, you are specifying a *range* value, not a *domain* value. For positional scales, the range is measured in pixels on the screen, so `x=alt.XValue(41)` tells the chart to draw a line 41 pixels from the left of the panel.

If you want to specify a domain value, the only way to do that in the current version of Altair is via either a dataset or a calculate transform; for example:

```python
base = alt.Chart(
    pd.DataFrame({'x':[41]})
).mark_rule(color='red', strokeDash=[4, 2]).encode(
    x='x'
)
```